# Object pattern training and recognition (Image based)

Tags: pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, object-recognition, google-goggles

Is there any c/c++ library for object pattern training and recognition? I need to implement feature and functionalities similar to what Google Goggles (http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text) does

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Tessarect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29):

> Tesseract is a free software optical character recognition engine for
>   various operating systems. Originally developed as proprietary
>   software at Hewlett-Packard between 1985 and 1995, it had very little
>   work done on it in the following decade. It was then released as open
>   source in 2005 by Hewlett Packard and UNLV. Tesseract development has
>   been sponsored by Google since 2006. It is released under the
>   Apache License, Version 2.0. Tesseract is considered one of
>   the most accurate free software OCR engines currently available.

You could find some information [here](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vs2008/doc/index.html) and [here](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vs2008/doc/programming.html). Source seems to be available at this link: `http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`